# How to generate random ID numbers that can't be reused in java?

Tags: java

For my current java project, I am trying to generate random `ID's` for registered users. So far I have been using  `min +(int) (Math.random()*((max-min)+1))` as my formula to generate the random number. The problem that I am facing is that sometimes the numbers repeat themselves and my application wouldn't work with them.

```
    int min = 1001;
    int max = 1050;
    
    for (int i=1; i<=1; i++)
    {
    int a = min +(int) (Math.random()*((max-min)+1));
    
    

     }
```

I have tried using and incorporating

```
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[100];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

but numbers generated would constantly come out as "null" and it would repeat the loop a few hundred times and flood my txt file.

Comment: Note that with `int i = 1;` your array and list will contain 1 `null` value, the one at index 0 initially. For the rest ("constantly come out as `null`" and "repeat the loop a few hundred times") you'd need to elaborate as the shuffled array alone wouldn't do that. Are you recreating the array each time you need an id?

Comment: [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). [`java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()).

Comment: Btw, when posting code please only post the relevant portions and format them to help us follow along your code (you want us to put effort into answers so please put effort into the question). As an example, all the UI related stuff (message diaglos, access to the text field, etc.) doesn't seem to be related to the question at all. Finally, please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry for the issues with the formatting, this is my first time posting on here. Next Time I will follow all the guidelines

Answer (score 6):

In general, random generators `Random` or `Math.random()` are not the correct ways to generate a unique id. As you mentioned, it could be repeated (and it will definitely be).

I would recommend two ways of generating `ID`.

The first one is to use `AtomicInteger`. This is good when your `ID` should be **unique** but **not random**.

```java
private static final AtomicInteger ID = new AtomicInteger(0);

public static String generateUniqueId() {
    return String.valueOf(ID.incrementAndGet());
}
```

The second one, which is preferable to me, is to use `UUID`. This is good when your `ID` should be as **unique** as **random**.

```java
public static String generateUniqueId() {
    return String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

---

Another one, I can mention is to use `System.nanoTime()`.

```java
public static String generateUniqueId() {
    return String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());
}
```

Long ago I had some investigation and find out that this is pretty stable for normal payload. But in general, it could retrieve the same value if you build such a system, that should generate `ID` so often.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating numbers I would recommend to generate UUID. The chance of a is collision is close to impossible.

```java
UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Otherwise if you want to stick with numbers I would recommend you to implement yourself some Sequence service within your application.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class SequenceService {

    private final AtomicLong ids;

    public SequenceService() {

        long initialValue = getInitialValue();
        this.ids = new AtomicLong(initialValue);
    }

    public long generateNextId() {
        return ids.incrementAndGet();
    }

    private long getInitialValue() {
        // this methods reads the last known leased id (e.g. from the file system)
    }
}
```

Comment: « much smaller » is a vast understatement. The specification for Version 4 UUID provides for a range of a total of 2^122, or 5.3×1036 (5.3 undecillion) possible values. The chance of collision in common usages is practically nil. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions).